# How to make this slider to auto play?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have download the slider from this [Site](http://tympanus.net/Development/ThumbnailGridAnimations/)
I am trying to get this [Slider](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/23/animations-for-thumbnail-grids/) to auto play but I can't seem to get it to work, Does anyone know how I can achieve this? i tried to play with the below code but can not get what i want.

```
 function init() {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tt-grid-wrapper'), function (el) {

        var grid = el.querySelector('.tt-grid'),
            items = [].slice.call(grid.querySelectorAll('li')),
            navDots = [].slice.call(el.querySelectorAll('nav > a')),
            isAnimating = false,
            current = 0;

        navDots.forEach(function (el, i) {
            el.addEventListener(eventtype, function (ev) {
                if (isAnimating || current === i) return false;
                ev.preventDefault();
                isAnimating = true;
                updateCurrent(i);
                loadNewSet(i);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 function init() {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tt-grid-wrapper'), function (el) {

        var grid = el.querySelector('.tt-grid'),
            items = [].slice.call(grid.querySelectorAll('li')),
            navDots = [].slice.call(el.querySelectorAll('nav > a')),
            isAnimating = false,
            current = 0;

        navDots.forEach(function (el, i) {
            el.addEventListener(eventtype, function (ev) {
                if (isAnimating || current === i) return false;
                ev.preventDefault();
                isAnimating = true;
                updateCurrent(i);
                loadNewSet(i);
            });
        });

        var delay = 1000;
        var num_frames = 4;
        var i = 1;

        setTimeout( function() { 
            if (isAnimating || current === i) return false;
            isAnimating = true;
            updateCurrent(i);
            loadNewSet(i);
            i >= 4 ? i = 0 : i++;
        } , delay);
};
```

Comment: it is sliding on click right now you can you help me to set it onload?